# Getting error, when using the "collapse" option in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Im currently using the Elasticsearch 5.2 version. As I was trying out the "collapse" feature, which is new, I am getting an error.

Error:

```
"Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [collapse]."
```

Request:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "country": "China"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "country"
  }
}
```

Anyone has any idea why this is occuring?

Comment: This is a new feature that has not yet been released but is slated to be released in ES 5.3.0.

Comment: Yeah. It was mentioned in the documentation under 5.x. Changed to 5.2 and the page says "not available". Thanks for saving my time.